# Can I restore an additional address of Bitcoin Core

Tags: bitcoin-core, recover-private-key

Once in Bitcoin Core I created an address to receive some payments from a faucet. After years I reopened the Bitcoin Core and started to synchronize it. After a while there was a crash, and I decided to remove the previous Bitcoin Core folder (it appeared to be in a USB hard drive and didn't get to Recycle Bin - when I decided to restore the removed files it was too late).
Then I reinstalled the Bitcoin Core, put there a wallet.dat from backup and successfully synchronized the blockchain. But I discovered - there's no address for the faucet, which I needed and there's no satoshi I expected. Apparently I created it before the backup (some previous history was there - so the wallet was restored - but without the latest address). So, should I consider the value on this address lost?

I tried to create the dump (`dumpwallet "dump.txt"`) and to find the master private key there to restore the private key of this address somehow. The dump file contains some `# extended private masterkey` (starts with *xprv*). Also I know the address, which I set to the faucet (`1J2ia2JZVoN8fqdvGYjkVaaX3A2C5BZzwj`). So I thought I can use this data in "Mnemonic Code Converter" (https://iancoleman.io/bip39/) (extended private masterkey to BIP32 Root Key input and selected the Bitcoin Core presets everywhere). Surprisingly enough the first generated entry contained my first default address, but I couldn't find neither of the other addresses from the dump file. The address from the faucet doesn't exist in the dump either. What do I do wrong?

Here is the address I'm talking about: https://www.blockchain.com/btc/address/1J2ia2JZVoN8fqdvGYjkVaaX3A2C5BZzwj

Answer (score -1):

New receive addresses are always generated in the same sequence for the same wallet. That is why if you have old `wallet.dat` you always can regenerate receive addresses even if they are created after the time you backuped your `wallet.dat`.

I mean you can, put your `wallet.dat` into bitcoin core and create new address to receive payments like you did before receiving payment years ago - newly generated address will be the same as before (`1J2ia2JZVoN8fqdvGYjkVaaX3A2C5BZzwj`). Now you have your lost private key regenerated.

If bitcoin core is already syncronized with blockchain, then your balance will be still incorrect and will not take into accont coins belonging to `1J2ia2JZVoN8fqdvGYjkVaaX3A2C5BZzwj`. You should rescan your local copy to correct this:

According to btcscan.org address `1J2ia2JZVoN8fqdvGYjkVaaX3A2C5BZzwj` received coins at block `657133`. Press Ctrl+T to open bitcoin core consle (if you are using GUI) and do the following command to rescan near missing block:

`rescanblockchain 657132 657134`

Now your balance is correct and you are able to spend it.

Answer (score -3):

Try it Electrum. Do import extended private masterkey

Comment: It would be helpful if you added details and a screenshot or two showing what you mean and how it helps answer the question.